# Unir polígonos / provincias en mapa

Tags: json

Estoy usando *QGIS* para eliminar fronteras y así unificar las provincias de cada comunidad autónoma.

Pongo ejemplo: *Andalucía*, está dividida en 8 provincias y *Extremadura* en 2.

Al unificar Andalucía, (selecciono las provincias a unificar, y elijo---> *vectorial -> herramientas de geoproceso -> dissolve*) me funciona, pero al querer hacerlo con *Extremadura*, ya no me permite realizar la misma operación.

Comment: Por si sabes ingles y no conocias el sitio, StackExchange tiene un sitio para [Sistemas de Informacion Geografica](http://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: No he usado qgis, pero imagino depende de si el conjunto que quieres disolver es topológicamente válido. Por ejemplo, que no haya autointersecciones y que los polígonos no compartan superficie sino sólo bordes.